# Autocomplete json format response couldn't shown in suggest box. Where did i go wrong?

Tags: jquery, json, autocomplete

Here is working code standalone without autocomplete.

```
function postVeJSON()
{
    var gelenJSONkurumlar;
    $.post("evrak_action.php",
        {isTipi:'kurumListesi',jsonMU:'evet'},
        function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    );
}
```

this gives me properly formatted json data as

[image: returnin json from server (php)]

But when i try to get it inside autocomplete ui with this code

```
$("#evrakKurum").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) { 
        $.ajax({
            url: "evrak_action.php",
            data: {isTipi:'kurumListesi',jsonMU:'evet'},
            dataType: "json", 
            type: "POST", 
            success: function(data) {
                response(data);
            }
        });
    }   
    ,
minLength:3
});
```

any error thrown or any messages shown.
Where did I go wrong?

Comment: *"any error thrown or any messages shown."* what does that mean? Do you get an error? If yes, please post it.

Comment: what does  response(data) do? try alert(data);

Comment: I uploded an image of returning json data (alert() box) but nothing appears here...

Comment: @FelixKling nothing happens :(   just trying it.

Comment: When i put alert instead of response i got '[object, object],[object,object].........' jsonlike data.

Comment: I guess you have to restructure your data. Assuming you are using jQuery UI, you can see [in the documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source), if you provide an array of objects, each object must have a `value` and `label` property.

Comment: @FelixKling data arrives as well formatted json. But autocomplete can't handle json data. [label:"data",label:"data"] for last try autocomplete put json data into suggestion box of ui letter by letter as it was a string http://image.caglarorhan.com/2013/3/8/82804221448278701046.jpg

Comment: My structured json data is: http://image.caglarorhan.com/2013/3/8/22031024118515711046.jpg

Comment: Well, you always have to **parse** JSON into native JS data types. Specifying `dataType: 'json'` usually does this automatically. If you see each letter in the select box, it means that you passed the response as string, and autocomplete treated the string as array of strings (an array of single characters). I know how your data looks like. It's an array objects, each having an `id` and `kurum_adi` property. But as I said, each object must have a `label` and `value` property.

Comment: @FelixKling can you give me a mini sample json syntax?

Comment: `[{"label": "myLabel", "value": "myValue"}]`.

Comment: Solved: In the `success:` when we get the json object (returns as string from server) make it a real array with `map()` method. I tried `push()` but not worked for me. As @FelixKling said should use `label:` and `value:` `//=========================================================<`
               `//return($(jQuery.parseJSON(data)).kurum_adi);`
          `response( $.map( data, function( item ) {`
          `return {`
          `label: item.kurum_adi,`
          `value: item.kurum_adi`
            `}`
                 `}));`